# Is It Possible to reverse the order of a msyqli_query after selecting?

Tags: php, sorting, mysqli

So I need to ORDER BY DATE DESC in my query, because I am grabbing the 5 most recent results.

```
$commentquery=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM user_comments WHERE 
content_id='$storyid' ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 5 ");
while ($comment=mysqli_fetch_array($commentquery)):
```

However, after I have my results, I would like to reverse order and loop through the oldest to newest of my 5 results.I tried placing mysqli_fetch_Array($commentquery) in a variable and doing an array reverse, but doesn't seem to be the way to do it.

Comment: can you dump the array for sample

Comment: You should post what you have tried exactly; getting all rows and doing an `array_reverse()` would definitely solve your problem, as would popping of items at the end of the array in a loop.

Comment: Certainly you can fetch _all_ result entries into memory and then iterate over them in any way you like, not only up and down. But that approach won't scale obviously, since you have to hold _all_ results in memory. To be able to process result entries in a way that scales for larger result sets you need to keep the result in the sql server and only fetch and process one entry at a time. That means you need to change the way the sql query defines the order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a query that orders the result of the current selection of records.

```
SELECT * FROM 
  (SELECT * 
   FROM user_comments 
   WHERE content_id='$storyid' 
   ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 5) last_five_comments 
ORDER BY date ASC
```

Comment: Thank you everyone for your answers - however this was the simplest and worked perfectly. Just selecting in a subquery and then ordering the subquery results the way I need. Simple!!! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't see why you don't just reverse the sort order of your query, where there's a will there's a way.

```
$commentquery=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM user_comments WHERE content_id='$storyid' ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 5 ");
$count = mysqli_num_rows($commentquery);
while ($count > 0) {
    $count--;
    mysqli_data_seek($commentquery, $count);
    $comment = mysqli_fetch_array($commentquery):

    // do things with $comment
}
```

Comment: Reversing the sort order of the query and getting the 5 *last* items is not as straight-forward as it might seem :-)

Comment: I've just re-read the question, and you're right :)